# Metasploitable 2 on VirtualBox. Virtualbox Host Interface Networking Error

Tags: virtualbox, interface

I get this message when I try to run Metasploitable 2 on VirtualBox VM 5.0.0 win.amd64:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Metasploitable 2.

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Host machine is a Windows 8.1
Processor: Intel(R) Celeron(R) 2955U @ 1.40GHz 
RAM: 8,00 GB
System: 64-bit OS and x64. based processor

Additional information:  Kali Linux/Linux mint and other linux distros runs in virtualbox

Any suggestion for solution?

The image below shows my network settings for Metasploitable in virtualbox

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRt0w.jpg

Comment: I followed one of the the tutorials for installing Metasploitable on virtuabox ( the "official", I think).  



When I used the free version of VMware workstation the problem didn't occur, even if I used similar settings as i virtualbox. 

Can it be anything with my network adapter settings on the host machine? 



[url=http://imgur.com/zh0Ofoz][img]http://i.imgur.com/zh0Ofoz.jpg?1[/img][/url]

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following and check if it works.

- **Open Virtual box**
- **Right click on the virtual machine. (In your case the Metasploitable 2 VM)**
- **Select Settings**

[image: Right CLick on settings]

- **Select the network tab**

[image: Select network tab]

- **Enable the network adapter**

[image]

- **Click on OK and then restart the Virtual machine**